# finding the clicked element in an array of references (useRef)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, components, use-ref

How can I find the clicked item if I have an array of referenced values, I used useRef

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const checkboxes = useRef({});
  var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
  var myArrValues = []
  const [arrValues, setArrValues] = useState(false)

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    myArrValues.push(i % 2 === 0)

  useEffect(() => {
    setArrValues(myArrValues)
  }, [])

  const setcheckBoxValue = (e) => {
    console.log(checkboxes);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map( (x, idx) =>
        <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          id={idx.toString()} 
          name={idx.toString()} 
          checked={arrValues[idx]}
          ref={ (el) => checkboxes.current[idx] = el } 
          onChange={(e) => setcheckBoxValue(e)}
        ></input>)
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the setcheckBoxValue method, I need to know which checkbox was clicked
Thanks in advance

Rafael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the ref (or the `arr` of unused characters) is doing anything useful here. If you want to toggle the state of a given checkbox, just keep track of the index being iterated over in the rendering closure, and pass it along when clicked:

```js
const { useRef, useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [arrValues, setArrValues] = useState(
    // use a function here to only create the initial array on mount
    () => Array.from(
      { length: 10 },
      (_, i) => i % 2 === 0
    )
  );

  const setcheckBoxValue = (i) => {
    setArrValues(
      arrValues.map((v, j) => j !== i ? v : !v)
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arrValues.map( (val, i) =>
        <input 
          key={i}
          type="checkbox" 
          checked={val}
          onChange={() => setcheckBoxValue(i)}
        ></input>)
      }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: The script is runnable as-is with no changes. The snippet uses Babel Standalone, but for your purposes you just need to copy over the contents of the `function App`. Assuming you're building with Webpack or something similar, you don't need the script tags, they're just there so that the snippet is runnable here with Babel Standalone

Comment: And what if n is unknown until I read some value in a database, what do you suggest me todo?

Comment: You mean the number of checkboxes? Wait until the database is read to render the component - don't call the component at all until the number is known.