# Handling an indetermined amount of states for n checkboxes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, components, state

I have this solution for handling a fix number of states for a fix number of checkboxes:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [arrValues, setArrValues] = useState(
    // use a function here to only create the initial array on mount
    () => Array.from(
      { length: 10 }
    )
  );

  const setcheckBoxValue = (i) => {
    setArrValues(
      arrValues.map((v, j) => j !== i ? v : !v)
    );
    console.log(arrValues);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arrValues.map( (val, i) =>
        <input 
          key={i}
          type="checkbox" 
          checked={val}
          onChange={() => setcheckBoxValue(i)}
        >

        </input>)
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the code it is 10, but, what if the length of the array is not known until I read some value in a database,

Rafael

Comment: [*Wait until the database is read to render the component - don't call the component at all until the number is known*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66591394/finding-the-clicked-element-in-an-array-of-references-useref#comment117718728_66591470) ?

Comment: Well then you can't initialise/set the value until you know? Just set it to something like `null` and then render a loading spinner or something until value is fetched

Comment: Check solution below. This is how I render fields dynamically. You should be able to do the same for a list of checkboxes. The example uses an object instead of an array, however I'm sure you could get array working as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. The example below is using an object rather than an array, but this is just example. Also, the “initialValues” could be easily generated from data (from database). These could be the undetermined values you mentioned.

```
const MyTest = () => {
  const initialValues = {
    values: { checkbox1: true, checkbox2: false, checkbox3: true }
  }
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialValues || {})

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target
    const value = target.checked
    const name = target.name

    setState((prevState) => ({
      values: {
        ...prevState.values,
        [name]: value
      }
    }))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, null, 2)}</pre>
      {state.values &&
        Object.keys(state.values).map((checkboxKey, i) => (
          <input
            name={checkboxKey}
            key={i}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={state.values[checkboxKey]}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: tank you for answering, tomorrow I'll do it

Comment: @Rafael did this answer your question?